# Run multiple python scripts with infinite loops parallely in an SH file

Tags: linux, sh

I've two Python scripts having infinite while loops inside them. I'd like to trigger both of'em parallelly and let it run in the background using an SH script file. If I run the python scripts separately via SH script file they are getting executed. However, if I try to run both at the same time, the script file is not getting executed. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my SH file configuration.

```
#!/bin/sh
source /data/test_venv/bin/activate
/data/test_venv/bin/python3 /data/CV_MQTT.py &
/data/test_venv/bin/python3 /data/CV_Flask.py &
```

Though the syntax is correct, I'm not sure what I'm missing in the above script.

Note - The access and permissions are available for this sh file.

Comment: can you add these to log errors so that we can understand what he error is?

`/data/test_venv/bin/python3 /data/CV_MQTT.py 2>/data/CV_MQTT_error.log &
/data/test_venv/bin/python3 /data/CV_Flask.py 2>/data/CV_Flask_error.log &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using subshells might help in this case. I have not executed below code myself; however, you can give it a try and see if you get what you expect.

```
#!/bin/sh
source /data/test_venv/bin/activate
(/data/test_venv/bin/python3 /data/CV_MQTT.py) &
(/data/test_venv/bin/python3 /data/CV_Flask.py) &
wait  # To wait until processes running inside subshells are complete
```

It is always good to use 'wait' with parallel subshells; however, in your case it might not make sense as the python scripts have infinite loops and are not going to complete :)

Regards,
Yuvraj

Comment: Wow, Thanks for sharing this Yuvaraj. Let me check this in my code.